# Is there a difference between starting GridGain nodes on the same local machine vs on different machines?

Tags: caching, gridgain

Given that a local machine has sufficient RAM, is there a difference between starting N GridGain nodes on that one local machine versus starting N GridGain nodes on N distinct machines (each of which, also has sufficient RAM)

I am looking at storing data in a GridGain cluster and then querying it to see the performance. Any tips or things I should look out for when dealing with this?

I am worried that starting more than one node on the same machine would have an affect, as that means latency between nodes is decrease (? this is a speculation). On the other hand, is there an approach to programmatically start and shutdown nodes on remote machines (under the same virtual network)? My desire to start nodes on the same machine stemmed from the fact that there are well documented ways to start and stop nodes, so long as they are on the same machine.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The only reason to start several nodes on one machine is to control JVM GC pauses. By splitting memory between multiple local machines, you can allocate less heap to every JVM and decrease GC pauses. Another way to decrease GC pauses, is to use [Offheap Memory](http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Off-Heap+Memory).
2. You can use [command-line](http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Visor+Management+Console) or [GUI Visor](http://entdoc.gridgain.org/latest/Visor+GUI) management console to automatically start/stop/restart remote nodes.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitriy for the quick response. Regarding (2), I understand visor can start and restart nodes. But the use case for me is I would like to start a node on a remote VM, perform a query question, then start another node on a seperate remote VM and query... and repeat. Similarly, with visor, if I remove a node from the topology, I cannot readd it to the topology (ie. if I query on a topology of 3 nodes and then wish to transition to 2 nodes). Is there a way to temporarily suspend a node from the topology?

Comment: Have you taken a look at `GridProjection` - which is a subset of nodes in the topology? You can create a grid projection over any subset of nodes, and then execute any computation over that projection. Will this work for you?

Comment: Hmm I looked into projections for a different reason but didn't think of that. How would that affect the cache? I have come to understand GridProjections allow me to perform operations using a subset o the nodes of the topology but what I was looking for was ways to include (or exclude) a subset of the nodes **from the cache** (and I can only think to do so by actually starting a grid or closing a grid), so that I can view the query performance as a function of the number of nodes (that which are interfacing the cache, as they are all marked as PARTITION_ONLY).

Comment: Got it, @s'-wh. You are right, the only way is to stop and start a node. Please take a look at `Grid.startNodes(...)` and `Grid.stopNodes(...)` methods.

Comment: Grid.startNodes(..) and it seems like the answer but I am having trouble with it as I don't get debug information. I've created the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188446/gridgain-programmatically-opening-nodes-using-ssh-through-grid-startnodes-api